# Factor the number $2^{11} - 1$ by fermat's factorization method

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I started with finding the smallest integer *k* such that $k^2 - (2^{11} - 1) >= 0$. 
But then I need the smallest *j*
where *j* = $2^6$, $2^6+1$, ... ,$\left(\frac{(2^{11}-1+1)}{2}\right)^2$ Such that *j*$^2$ $-(2^{11}-1)$ is a square, and I'm not sure on how I should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

If $2^{11}-1\equiv0\pmod p$, then $p-1=11k$. Also we only need check divisors less than $\sqrt{2^{11}}<64$, so the only candidate divisor is $p=23$. Calculation shows that $2^{11}-1=23\cdot89$.

Comment: Much more efficient than Fermat's method (but with the factors so far apart, even naive trial division seems more efficient than Fermat's method here, or at least on par)

Comment: How do you get $p-1 = 11k$ from $2^{11}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}?

Answer (score 1):

I will start with the $\lceil \sqrt{2^{11}-1} \rceil=46.$

If I implement Fermat's factorization method, I will realized that $$56^2-(2^{11}-1)=33^2$$

Hence the factors are $56-33=23$ and $56+33=89$.

Python code:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_dVMubKpFkoPggbp.py

Comment: I didn't know it turned out to be that simple. Thanks